# PyTorch index in a batch

Tags: python, pytorch

Given tensor `IN` of shape `(A, B, C, D)` and index tensor `IDX` of shape `[A, B, C]` with `torch.long` values in `[0, C)`, how can I get a tensor `OUT` of shape `(A, B, C, D)` such that:

```
OUT[a, b, c, :] == IN[a, b, IDX[a, b, c], :]
```

This is trivial without dimensions `A` and `B`:

```py
# C = 2, D = 3
IN = torch.arange(6).view(2, 3)
IDX = torch.tensor([0,0])

print(IN[IDX])
# tensor([[0, 1, 2],
#         [0, 1, 2]])
```

Obviously, I can write a nested for loop over A and B. But surely there must be a vectorized way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the perfect use case for [`torch.gather`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.gather.html). Given two 4d tensors, `input` the input tensor and `index` the tensor containing the indices for `input`, calling `torch.gather` on `dim=2` will return a tensor out shaped like `input` such that:

```
out[i][j][k][l] = input[i][j][index[i][j][k][l]][l]
```

In other words, `index` indexes dimension n°3 of `input`.

Before applying such function though, notice all tensors must have the same number of dimensions. Since `index` is only 3d, we need to insert and expand an additional 4th dimension on it. We can do so with the following lines:

```
>>> idx_ = idx[...,None].expand_as(x)
```

Then call the `torch.gather` function

```
>>> x.gather(dim=2, index=idx_)
```

---

You can try out the solution with this code:

```
>>> A = 1; B = 2; C=3; D=2

>>> x = torch.rand(A,B,C,D)
tensor([[[[0.6490, 0.7670],
          [0.7847, 0.9058],
          [0.3606, 0.7843]],

         [[0.0666, 0.7306],
          [0.1923, 0.3513],
          [0.5287, 0.3680]]]])

>>> idx = torch.randint(0, C, (A,B,C))
tensor([[[1, 2, 2],
         [0, 0, 1]]])

>>> x.gather(dim=2, index=idx[...,None].expand_as(x))
tensor([[[[0.7847, 0.9058],
          [0.3606, 0.7843],
          [0.3606, 0.7843]],

         [[0.0666, 0.7306],
          [0.0666, 0.7306],
          [0.1923, 0.3513]]]])
```